# Suppress unused variable warning in gfortran using -Wextra and -Wall fortran

Tags: debugging, fortran, gfortran

I'm debugging a large code with the flags `-Wall` and `-Wextra`, but I'm getting hundreds of `Unused parameter` warnings which I'm not interested in.  Is there a way to suppress only these warnings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply append `-Wno-unused-parameter`... See [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/Error-and-Warning-Options.html#Error-and-Warning-Options) for details.

From the [docs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/Error-and-Warning-Options.html#Error-and-Warning-Options):

> Each of these specific warning options also has a negative form
>   beginning -Wno- to turn off warnings; for example, -Wno-implicit.

Comment: Thanks!  I missed the key `Each of these specific warning options also has a negative form beginning -Wno- to turn off warnings` section when I saw that page...